# Android Browser that Saves and Fills Passwords

Tags: 2.1-eclair, browser, password

**Is there a browser I can install that stores passwords just like regular desktop    browsers?**
I'd only use it for unimportant passwords, so I'm really not worried about security. Anything that saves and auto fills my passwords is fine.

*Running a motorola-milestone.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard Android browser does this for me on most (non-banking type) websites. When I start typing my username into the login box it shows a drop down of names used in that login box before. Selecting one of those fills the password box in too.

If you go into the browser and press <kbd>Menu</kbd> -> **More** -> **Settings** and then scroll down the settings window to the **Privacy Settings** section, there's a tick-box there for **Remember Form Data**, then if you scroll down a bit further to **Security Settings**, there's a tickbox for **Remember Passwords**. make sure that both of those are ticked and you should be ok.

I'm on a Galaxy S running the official Samsung Froyo 2.2 release, and I'm sure my old HTC Magic running stock Android Donut 1.6 did this too.

Comment: Now that you mentioned, I tried a couple other sites and it worked. Looks like it's this specific one I'm having trouble with. That is weird, it's a standard login and it works fine on desktop browsers.

Comment: @Bruce could be the name of those fields?  Browsers typicall look for username/password ids on the text box fields

Comment: Could be, the ids are not in English so it might not be recognizing them. Still strange though, cause I'm using the Portuguese version of the OS (browser included).

Answer (score 2):

Opera Mini 5 also includes the ability to save / remember a user's login credentials.

LastPass and KeePass also have Android editions that remember your logins / passwords, although they aren't browsers.

Comment: Paid version of LastPass includes an Android browser

Answer (score 2):

There's a LastPass plugin for Dolphin browser that's great.  It will remember all of your passwords and sync with the desktop if you use LastPass there as well.  Personally I also prefer the look and performance of the Dolphin browser to the stock Android one.